# Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable in WP 8.1

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, jump-list

I am developing a music player app in WP 8.1 & I am trying to implement Jump List feature into it.
To implement jump list, I am following the sample given [here](https://modernography.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/making-wp8-1-jumplists-better/).

I am making some necessary changes to the available code & that's how I am implementing the desired feature as my knowledge in C#, MVVM & WP 8.1 is minimal.

But I am facing an error in my ViewModel at line

```
var items = ContactModel.CreateSampleData();
```

and the error is:

```
Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable
```

What could be the possible reason???? Can anyone help me understand where I went wrong.

```
using System.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using JumpListSample.Common.JumpList;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using System;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Search;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace JumpListSample.ViewModels
{
    public class ContactsViewModel
    {
        private IList data;
        public IList Data
        {
            get
            {
                if (data == null)
                {
                    var items = ContactModel.CreateSampleData();
                    data = items.ToAlphaGroups(x => x.Name);
                }
                return data;
            }
        }
        private CollectionViewSource collection;

        public CollectionViewSource Collection
        {
            get
            {
                if (collection == null)
                {
                    collection = new CollectionViewSource();
                    collection.Source = Data;
                    collection.IsSourceGrouped = true;
                }
                return collection;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ContactModel
    {
        // constructor
        public ContactModel()
        {
            Name = "name";
            Albumart = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.scale-240.png"));
        }

        public async  static void CreateSampleData()
        {
            ObservableCollection<ContactModel> data = new ObservableCollection<ContactModel>();

            try
            {
                IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> MusicLibrary = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByAlbum);
                foreach (IStorageItem item in MusicLibrary)
                {
                    ContactModel obj = new ContactModel();
                    IStorageItem musicItem = item;
                    obj.Name = musicItem.Name;
                    obj.Albumart = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.scale-240.png"));
                    data.Add(obj);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
            } 
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ImageSource Albumart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Demo code can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qan53xs9236cf30/JumpListSample.zip?dl=0).

Comment: ContactModel.CreateSampleData() doesn't return anything (technically it returns void) so you can't assign it to a variable. You probably want to return "data" public async  Task<ObservableCollection<ContactModel>> CreateSampleData(). BTW an empty "finally" statement is meaningless

Comment: I should also add that you would have to "await" the result. ie. var items = await ContactModel.CreateSampleData();

Comment: I'll be honest I didn't delve too deeply into the head space of all this but "items" would be a list so you would be return "data". ie The entire list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with commenter Clint Good's suggestion. Your `CreateSampleData()` method appears to be responsible for initializing a collection of `ContactModel` instances. Presumably, you are calling this from the `Data` property because these are the items you want to use to initialize the `data` field.

That said, you have a serious problem: C# properties do not support the `async`/`await` pattern. One idiom for addressing this is to asynchronously initialize the backing field, and then raise a property-changed event when the initialization has completed. Unfortunately, your `ContactsViewModel` class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or inherit `DependencyObject` (the two ways XAML-based programs handle property-change notification).

Taking all that together and making the necessary changes to your code, you'd wind up with something like this:

**ContactsViewModel:**

```
public class ContactsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private IList data;
    public IList Data
    {
        get
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                // Ignore the returned Task...we're not going to do anything with it
                var _ = InitData();
            }

            // Caller should handle null. If not, need to return "new Data[0]" here instead
            return data;
        }
    }

    private async Task InitData()
    {
        // Catch _specific_ exceptions here, if necessary

        var items = await ContactModel.CreateSampleData();
        data = items.ToAlphaGroups(x => x.Name);
        OnPropertyChanged("Data");
    }

    private CollectionViewSource collection;

    public CollectionViewSource Collection
    {
        get
        {
            if (collection == null)
            {
                collection = new CollectionViewSource();
                collection.Source = Data;
                collection.IsSourceGrouped = true;
            }
            return collection;
        }
    }
}
```

**ContactModel:**

```
public class ContactModel
{
    // constructor
    public ContactModel()
    {
        Name = "name";
        Albumart = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.scale-240.png"));
    }

    public async static Task<ObservableCollection<ContactModel>> CreateSampleData()
    {
        ObservableCollection<ContactModel> data = new ObservableCollection<ContactModel>();

        IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> MusicLibrary = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByAlbum);
        foreach (IStorageItem item in MusicLibrary)
        {
            ContactModel obj = new ContactModel();
            IStorageItem musicItem = item;
            obj.Name = musicItem.Name;
            obj.Albumart = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.scale-240.png"));
            data.Add(obj);
        }

        return data;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Albumart { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I have also removed your try/catch entirely. It is very bad to simply swallow exceptions. If you think you need to handle any exceptions, handle them in the caller (i.e. `ContactsViewModel.InitData()`) where you can do something useful and notify the user if necessary (but only handle specific exceptions, ones you know how to respond to).